# PuTTY command line user input

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty

I am trying to write a batch file to automate a PuTTY script. Right now the script successfully logs into the SSH server with this line

```
putty.exe -ssh user@ipaddress -pw password -m commands.txt > log.txt
```

My problem is that once it's logged in the server prompts me to hit *"Ctrl+y to begin"* afterwards it asks me to press *"Enter"*. How would I imitate that in my `commands.txt` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Plink (PuTTY command-line tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

It is a console application, hence it allows input redirection.

Create a text file that contains <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> character followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> character. I.e. `0x19` and `0x0A`. And then follow with your commands.

Then you can do

```
plink -ssh user@ipaddress -pw password < input.txt
```